# What language standard should I use if I want to at least differentiate between UK english and American English?

Tags: c#, architecture, localization, iso

As in the subject, i'm designing a system that will accept documents in various languages, submitters want to be able to say this was 'written in American English' or 'written in United Kingdom English' (which of course is just 'english' but that's perhaps beside the point as it's still a distinct dialect)

I've been looking at ISO-639-3 but that doesn't appear to account for the 'American English' addition

Has anyone got any ideas?

Comment: IT's the same language, but a different country. Usually it would be designated by `en_US` and `en_UK`. Where `en` is the language code and `US` is the country. E.g. Belgian Dutch would be `nl_BE`, in the Netherlands it is `nl_NL`. Same language, different country.

Comment: Is something like "written in Texas American English" or "written in North Russian Dialect" of a concern or just "en-US"/"en-UK" (i.e. used for .Net culture names) is enough?

Comment: Sure, my natural instinct is to use en-US and en-GB for example, but what standard is that? I just need a standard to reference for an API document I want to be able to give to implementers. Based on the answer below from Jukka it looks like it's a 'Language-Region variant of RFC 5646' - which doesn't sound particularly glamorous, would that be the right way to describe it?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I don't think that I mind about Texas American English vs. American English - it might be nice to know the option is there if I need it. I should mention these 'documents' in my system can describe videos and mainly, the language the video is narrated/voiced/transcripted in

Comment: RFC is generally the best existing way to specify something. Also if you are fine with just list of cultures supported by .Net and corresponding names you'll save significant effort to everyone...

Comment: @HenriCook *"my natural instinct is to use en-US and en-GB for example, but what standard is that?"* [IETF Language Tags](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IETF_language_tag) might be the standard you're looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you mention ISO 639-3, it seems that you are looking for language *codes*. Then use `en-US` for US English, `en-GB` for British English.

Reference: [BCP 47](http://www.rfc-editor.org/info/bcp47), especially the “Tags for Identifying Languages” part, which is currently [RFC 5646](http://www.rfc-editor.org/info/rfc5646).

Comment: Thanks Jukka, i've mentioned it in the comments above but if I want to use the Language-Region variant of RFC 5646 - how do I describe that? Is it a standard in its own right?

Comment: RFC 5646 is (part of) a BCP, Best Current Practice document, which is in practice rather similar to Internet standard (i.e., a RFC with Internet standard status assigned to it), but not quite. It’s certainly something that you can cite, though of course not as a standard in the ISO parlance.